# I am trying to add colors to buttons when a button is clicked. The buttons are under ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

This is the html where the seats are getting generated inside ng-repeat directive. ng-class has been used to add colors when a seat is selected. But it is not working.

You can see my code in a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manit_kant/mym34oc0/) and below:

```
<body class="text-center" ng-app="movieApp" ng-controller="movieController">

<div id="content"> <span>
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" required>
        Number of Seats: <input type="text" ng-model="seat" required>
    </span>

</div>
<div id="button">
    <button ng-click="Select()">Start Selecting</button>
</div>
<div ng-if="selected">
    <div>Row A 
<span ng-repeat="value in values" ng-class="{ 'selected-class-name': $event == selectedIndex }" ng-click="SeatSelected($event)">
            <input type="button" id={{"A"+value}} >
        </span>

    </div>
    <div>Row B 
<span ng-repeat="value in values" ng-class="{'selected':$event = selectedRow}" ng-click="SeatSelected($event)">
            <input type="button" id={{"B"+value}} >
        </span>

    </div>
    <div>Row C 
<span ng-repeat="value in values" ng-class="{'selected':$event = selectedRow}" ng-click="SeatSelected($event)">
            <input type="button" id={{"C"+value}} >
        </span>

    </div>
    <div>Row D 
<span ng-repeat="value in values" ng-class="{'selected':$event = selectedRow}" ng-click="SeatSelected($event)">
            <input type="button" id={{"A"+value}} >
        </span>

    </div>
    <button ng-click=Confirm()>Confirm Selection</button>
    <div ng-if="confirmed" class="text-center">Create a Table
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{header.name}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
                <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.seat}}</td>
                <td>{{row.seatSelected}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML code. A demo of the above code would be fine too.

Comment: please provide your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manit_kant/mym34oc0/

Comment: Have a look at `ng-mousedown`

Comment: @gaynorvader - can you elaborate a bit? or any fiddle link for the same? Please understand the buttons are getting generated using ng-repeat and I am trying to apply color to a button on click of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hv9ssxuf/

I've added `angular.element(event.toElement).toggleClass('selected');` on seat click, and it works fine for me.

Hope it helps.